# upgrading from 12.10 to 14.04 LTS error

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 12.10

I am trying to upgrade from my ubuntu server from 12.10 to 14.04 only using putty. I dont have a desktop for my server. Please let me know how should I upgrade.

When i write the command

> sudo do-release-upgrade

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 145, in 
    fetcher.run_options += ["--mode=%s" % options.mode,
AttributeError: type object 'DistUpgradeFetcherCore' has no attribute 'run_options'

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but your are too late with this. You can not go directly from 12.10 (not an LTS and already end of life) to 14.04 and need to go through 13.04 (is end of life so no longer an upgrade path available), 13.10 (is end of life so no longer an upgrade path available) and then 14.04.

You should have installed and used 12.04 (LTS) and not a none-LTS release as a server for an upgrade from 12.04(.2) directly to 14.04.

Your best option is to plan a re-install of 14.04. And yes, I know it is problematic when this is a production system. We had the same issue long ago and got us another computer to do this to keep downtime to a minimum. Set up the new system, check it, make it available to key users and when they are happy replace the old one with this one. The current one can then be used as a backup system.

Comment: Can I uninstall 12.10 and re install 14.04 LTS within one day? I dont have a backup computer right now. When I tried to install new packages I faced this issue. 12.10 was installed by someone else, not by me. :( Is there any blog for the installation of 14.04 after uninstalling 12.10

Comment: You do no uninstall 12.10. You install 14.04 over the current install. If you can do it in a day is ... not really possible to say, it depends on how well you can plan it ;-)  You need to make a backup and make sure you can restore it.  You need to save settings for the servers you run (apache, mysql etc). If this was not your install ... I'd say you might have a hard time. -best- method would be to set it up on another computer and start implementing that one and leave this current one as is (and replace it with the new one).